# Download SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Report as PDF from URL with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

As it is mentioned in title, I meet a problem. User inputs DB and PoNum parameters on web page and hits submit button. After generating SSRS url from backend with C#, the following code uses Controller.Response to let user download the PDF file. Here is my code:

```
    public void DownloadSSRSReport(string DB, int PoNum)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int thisIns_ID = int.MinValue;
        if (Poinstl.installation.ContainsKey(DB))
        {
            Poinstl.installation.TryGetValue(DB, out thisIns_ID);
        }
        //Generate a SSRS url in the following part with stringbuilder.
        sb.Append("http://.../installationID=");
        sb.Append(thisIns_ID);
        sb.Append("&PoNo=");
        sb.Append(PoNum);
        sb.Append("&rs:Format=pdf&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=True ");

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
        //Use default credentials to handle 401 unauthorized error.
        req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            Stream fStream1 = httpWebResp.GetResponseStream();

            byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream1);
            if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SSRSReport.pdf");
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                Response.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            httpWebResp.Close();
        }

    }
```

Right now the code above has no error or exception during run time. But after hitting submit button from web page this file is not downloaded. I use google developer tool to monitor the status, here is what I get:
[image]

I have no idea why client user cannot download this PDF file. Is there something wrong with my C# code? By the way, I can use URL to download SSRS PDF report directly. I omit some important message in URL above.